# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable in driver.title()

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, page-title

In the code below I am trying to print the tab title and it open the tab but after that python giving me a TypeError and the program crashes.

```
from selenium import webdriver
path = "C:\Program Files\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get() # in the parentheses is a link like https://link.com/
print(driver.title())
driver.quit()
```

What is the problem? and how can I fix it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### driver.title

[*title*](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.title) is an attritibute, but not a method. It returns the title of the current page.

Usage:

```
title = driver.title
```

---

### Solution

You need to remove the parenthesis. So effectively, the line of code will be:

```
print(driver.title)
```